# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `label` of type `object` supplied to `Field`, expected `string`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, label, warnings

I have a field like this:

```
<Field
name="invoice"
label={
  <React.Fragment>
    Click the button{' '}
    <IconTooltip/>
  </React.Fragment>
}
inputType="checkbox"
/>
```

I tried to add the icon in the label name. The code is working well. But it keeps warning me:

***react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:118 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `label` of type `object` supplied to `Field`, expected `string`.***

Is there any way i can fix that?

I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: It means you're providing the wrong type to the `label` prop. It only expects a string, but you're passing a react fragment. Change the prop type to also accept a node.

Comment: The error is telling you everything. _"Invalid prop label of type __object__ supplied to `Field`, expected __string__."_ If this is a 3rd-party component check the documentation.

Comment: If it's a third party library, then you'll have to pass it a string, you won't be able to add a tooltip to the label.

Comment: Thank you so much you guys. So that mean i can not fix that in any way? there is the way that i can change the prop type, i am confused how i can do that.

Comment: How did u fix that ?

Comment: @chaitu605 i change the prop type to node. here is label type to node.